# performing .str().c_str() operation on ostringstream object giving core dump

Tags: c++, stringstream

My code  is as below

```
std::ostringstream tmpstr, tmpstr2;
for( /* something */ )
{
    //writting inside tmpstr
}

tmpstr2 << tmpstr.rdbuf();
cout << "assigned to tmpstr2"; 
out <<tmpstr2.str().c_str() ; // Where out is ostrstream& out
```

This is last stack call in dump :-

`std::basic_ostringstream<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream`

This last line when executed gives me a core dump . I am unable to understand the reason behind it . Can someone let me know if  i am performing an operation that is `invalid` but is not a comilation error .

Comment: Probably the problem is in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: The `.c_str()` is not necessary in any case.

Comment: It shouldnt be hard to create a minimal compilable testcase for others to experience the same behaviour...

Comment: You need to post a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example - http://sscce.org/

Comment: str() object goes out of scope just after calling the function , So by the time we put c_str() in the argument, the std::string object is cleared .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have corrupted your memory with another statement. It's hard to guess without seeing the actual code, but the best guess would be that you write out of bounds of something allocated before tmpstr or a stack-array directly afterwards.

either way, memory that should actually belong to the stream object is overwritten causing the stream object to break. The core dump happens after the actual broken line because it wasn't detected. You wrote over some bounds but ended up in your program's memory and not outside. In particular, in tmpstr's memory.

Comment: can a `rdbuf` operation be performed on tmpstr after `tmpstr.str().c_str()` is it legal .?

Comment: yes, it is legal. i assume there has to be an eorror in some code unrelated to ''tmpstr''